# how to convert linq query result to arraylist?

Tags: linq, arraylist

I tried the following coding to convert LINQ query to ArrayList, but the error occurs

> 'Cannot Implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List to
>   System.Collections.ArrayList'

the coding is,

```
var qry1 = (from a in obj.table1
                       join b in obj.table2
                       on a.id1 equals b.id1                       
                       select new
                       {
                          b.name,
                          b.id
                     });

           ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

           al = qry1.ToList();
```

how to convert query result to ArrayList.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you *really* need an ArrayList? I'd try to avoid using the non-generic collections if at all possible.

Comment: Forget the ArrayList, in 99.999% you don't need it. Use the strong typed `List<T>` instead. That's what you already get from `ToList`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

al.AddRange((from a in obj.table1
                       join b in obj.table2
                       on a.id1 equals b.id1                       
                       select new
                       {
                          b.name,
                          b.id
                     }).ToList());
```

If you really want to use ArrayList.